# Add views inside Iphone application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

Hey all i've tried to add an other view it work properly but  it look like a tableview I want it just like the first one how can i change the view to be like what I want not tableview 
btw this is my flip button code :

```
- (IBAction)flip:sender{

    // create a new SecondViewController
   SecondViewController *playback = 
   [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

   // set the transition style to fade
   playback.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
   playback.delegate = self; // set playback's delegate to self

   // show the PlaybackViewController
   [self presentModalViewController:playback animated:YES];
   [playback release]; // release the playback PlaybackViewController
} // end method flip:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SecondViewController *playback

is it a subclass of UITableViewController?
if it's a subclass of UITableViewController then it will have a table automatically

Comment: hey first thank u for answer my question.
really I don't know if it's a subclass of UITableViewController , after reading a lot of books and make some google search finally I got this code.

Comment: @bobj-c
well, I am assuming SecondViewController is a class made by you.
then in that case you can check out the .h file
is it something like

@implementation SecondViewController:UITableViewController

?